# Ruby 'require bunny' triggers what looks like a circular require

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

This case has me stumped. I am writing a pretty simple Sinatra app which is causing what looks like a circular require issue specifically with `require "bunny"`. Here is some evidence which by the way is after lots of trials, moving code around, commenting out and so on:

As you can see I put a break point just before the require statement:

```
rake test
[MAINAPP Starting! Rack: test]
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/lib/sqlite3/pragmas.rb:301: warning: method redefined; discarding old integrity_check
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.12/lib/sqlite3/pragmas.rb:107: warning: previous definition of integrity_check was here

[1, 10] in /Volumes/MonsterHD/mydev/nanotwitter/services/nt_service.rb
    1: require 'byebug'
    2: require_relative "../services/service_dispatch"
    3:
    4: byebug
=>  5: require 'bunny'
    6:
    7: class NtService
    8:   def initialize
    9:     @requests = 0
   10:     @running = false
```

Now I verify that the Bunny class is not yet defined:

```
(byebug) Bunny
*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant Bunny

nil
(byebug) next
```

Now I step over the 'require' and all hell breaks loose. A very long and apparently repetitive stack trace that includes errors referring to circular requires. Here are all the details: https://gist.github.com/pitosalas/de54212ddeac66328c02d64156845c8c

What can I try next?

Comment: What does `ruby -rubygems -rbunny` output? That's the most minimal way of testing this thing. It could be you've hit a snag in that particular version of the Ruby library, but it should work. I've used it on 2.3.1 and 2.3.3.

Comment: That by itself just goes into waiting for input. Did you mean doing that with my Sinatra app as the param?

Comment: When you're faced with a problem like this you've got to start ruling out things that might be interfering. If that command ran then it's *possible* to require `bunny` starting with a blank slate, so that's good. The question is what's causing the trouble? My instinct is to blame `byebug` but that could be wrong.

Comment: thanks @tadman: nah thats wrong because it happens without bye bug. I will have to start cutting my app into 1/2 and 1/2 again until I find it. Anyone else  have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
gem install bunny
```

I think this will solve your problem.

or upgrade your ruby version

```
require "bunny"
```